# Push Notification if App is Closed

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am developing push enabled allpication. For that I have Integrated  " Push Collector "  sample from  http://developer.blackberry.com/native/sampleapps/ .and hard coded app-id,PPG-URL etc.

now my question is if my push enabled appication is closed, can my App get the push messages ?

I want my app to get the push messages even  if it is closed? If it is possible, how to get it done.

I am new to BlackBerry Platform Features and BB 10 development.

Please help,

Thanks!!!

Comment: From memory, this is what happens by default.  Review the documentation and see.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where the new short running headless application API is applicable. One of the triggers that can result in the headless part of the application running is the receipt of push data. Start with the documentation here: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/headless_apps/